# Arcanist API - A way to return user email address using username?

Tags: json, api, arcanist

An Arcanist API call-conduit statement using method user.query (below) successfully returns a lot of information about the user from Phabricator through the already set-up conduit between Arcanist and Phabricator, but I'm interested in retrieving the users email address.  **Any suggestions?**

```
$ echo {\"usernames\": [\"jdoe\"]} | arc call-conduit user.query
```

Waiting for JSON parameters on stdin...

```
{"error":null,"errorMessage":null,
    "response":[{
        "phid":"PHID-USER-4fltrivg3apuizheic7s",
        "userName":"jdoe",
        "realName":"John Doe",
        "image":"http:\/\/xxxxxxxxx.global.ldap.wan\/res\/phabricator\/3eb28cd9\/rsrc\/image\/avatar.png",
        "uri":"http:\/\/xxxxxxxxxx.global.ldap.wan\/p\/jdoe\/",
        "roles":["verified","approved","activated"]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Conduit Method which returns user email addresses.

None but `user.whoami` returns it:

```
{
  "phid": "PHID-USER-i3xveobs3ezomrdodufi",
  "userName": "OCram",
  "realName": "Marco Blessing",
  "image": "https://p.phcdn.net/file/data/@secure/hcirbpnua7jzcsc54rtn/PHID-FILE-qxw7pwcn6ag6dtopf2bi/profile",
  "uri": "https://secure.phabricator.com/p/OCram/",
  "roles": [
    "verified",
    "approved",
    "activated"
  ],
  "primaryEmail": "marco.blessing@googlemail.com"
}
```

But this doesn't help you to get email addresses from other users.